# Поиск в массиве БД PostgreSQL + Nest

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Всем привет! В БД имеется заказ + статус:

```
{
  id: 1,
  status: [status: "Отправлено"]
}
```

Задача в том, что с помощью **.findAndCount** нужно находить все статусы по **query** , который приходит в запросе, например, если **query**=**"Отправлено"**, то нужно возвращать из БД все подходящие по условию результаты.

Пример моего текущего запроса

```
const result = await this.findAndCount({
  where: {
    id: id ? Equal(+id) : null,
    status: status ? In([{ status }]) : null,
  },
  order: { id: "DESC" },
  take: size,
  skip: (page - 1) * size,
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, т.к. в этом я ещё дилетант :)

Comment: const result = await this.findAndCount({
  where: {
    id: id ? Equal(+id) : null,
    status: status ? ILike(`%${status}%`) : null,
  },
  order: { id: "DESC" },
  take: size,
  skip: (page - 1) * size,
});

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov если Вы хотели написать status: status? ILike("%" + status+ "%") : null, то такой вариант выдает ошибку: operator does not exist: jsonb ~~* unknown

Comment: const result = await this.findAndCount({
  where: {
    id: id ? Equal(+id) : null,
    status: query ? ILike(`%${query}%`) : null,
  },
  order: { id: "DESC" },
  take: size,
  skip: (page - 1) * size,
});

Comment: вот что хотел) опечатка вышла 
если тут тоже будет ошибка, значит проблема в строка и делаем так
const result = await this.findAndCount({
  where: {
    id: id ? Equal(+id) : null,
    status: status ? In( () => {
      return this.createQueryBuilder()
        .select("jsonb_array_elements(status)->>'status'")
        .from(Order, "order")
        .where("order.status @> :query", { query: { status: status } })
        .getQuery();
    }) : null,
  },
  order: { id: "DESC" },
  take: size,
  skip: (page - 1) * size,
});

Comment: Честно говоря, в обоих случаях пишет ошибку синтаксиса. Во втором случае просто: Argument of type '() => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly unknown[] | FindOperator '

Comment: может я не так понял вопрос